# Move one screen row up/down in a multi-line text

Tags: vim, editors

I have a multiline text in my Vim editor as, [image]

One line of text is spread across multiple lines as shown above. For editing, i would like to move up/down one display line (screen-row) at a time.

But pressing down arrow takes me to the dead end which is not desired.

How can I navigate in a multiline text using the arrow keys?

Note: In other editors like emacs, gedit, I don't see this problem. When I press down arrow, it goes one level down in the screen display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command `gj` moves the cursor one screen line down and similarly `gk` moves it up by one screen line.

Comment: See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946421/vim-moving-with-hjkl-in-long-lines-screen-lines  for info on how to remap the cursor keys to support this.